# How to extract variables from a reactiveValues dataframe R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing an app that requires metadata, and am reading a metadata file into R using Shiny.  I need to be able to access the columns in that file (such as TZ, or timezone) later.  Here is my code for reading the file in and displaying it with DT:renderDataTable:

```
  # This uploads & displays the Metadata file
  metadata <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$metadataUpload, {
    output$metadataTable <- renderDataTable({
     metadata <- read.csv(input$metadataPath)}, editable = T, filter = 'top',
    )
  })
```

Once it's read in, it's the variable 'metadata', but I am not able to access the variables in the data frame for some reason (keep getting NULL's returned).  Shouldn't I be able to access the different variables using code like metadata$TZ?  If not, how do I access those variables?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't nest one reactive block inside another.
2. `renderDataTable` doesn't return a data.frame, it takes a frame (or frame-like object) as input, and renders it into HTML-ish content for presentation within a shiny environment.

I think you want something like one of the following:

```r
  metadata <- reactiveVal() # treat metadata like a getter/setter function
  observeEvent(input$metadataUpload, {
    tmpdat <- read.csv(input$metadataPath)}, editable = T, filter = 'top')
    metadata(tmpdat)
  })
  output$metadataTable <- renderDataTable({
    metadata()
  })
```

or

```r
  metadata <- reactiveValues() # treat metadata like a "named list"-like object
  observeEvent(input$metadataUpload, {
    metadata$something <- read.csv(input$metadataPath)}, editable = T, filter = 'top')
    # now, 'something' is a frame within the named list 'metadata'
  })
  output$metadataTable <- renderDataTable({
    metadata$something
  })
```

I suggest you read https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.5.0/reactiveValues.html.